# Different ways run an iOS application

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, macos, ios-simulator

It there a list of methods so we can run and test an iOS application?

Here testing does not mean unit testing or code testing. Let's assume my application is 100 % perfect from the coding point of view. Now Ii want to use the application. The method may be running the application on a simulator, an iPhone device, an iPad device etc.

Is it even possible that we can adopt different methods to install the application on the iOS device that is [jailbroken](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOS_jailbreaking) and the one that is not. The objective of my question is to list all the such possible ways that may help on the way to test or run your iOS application.

Comment: lots of time people don't find the resource to feel the application he developed either on simulator or on real device. So this question is intended to focus on such situation. For eg if i don't have real iPhone , then one way is to test on iPhone SDK. But if the developer is not using mac pc , then in such case he even don't have SDK as well. So try to feel the soul of question before down vote the answers. This may spoil the importance and usability of question.

Comment: If he doesn't have the SDK, then how did he develop the app? I don't accept your premise.

Comment: I hope app can also developed in some other method rather than just using the native process, right ?

Answer (score 3):

You can do unit testing for iOS applications with Xcode 4. Unit testing increases productivity and raises code quality.

You can see more details about unit testing [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/UnitTesting/00-About_Unit_Testing/about.html).

You can see more details about setting up logic unit tests [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/UnitTesting/02-Setting_Up_Unit_Tests_in_a_Project/setting_up.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002143-CH3-SW5).

Also, you can see a top 10 tips for testing iPhone applications [here](http://blog.testlabs.com/2009/08/top-10-tips-for-testing-iphone.html).

**For deploying**, these are the possible ways without jailbreaking:

1. Connect your device and run you project to a device instead of the simulator.
2. Create IPA and install through iTunes
3. Create IPA and install through [TestFlight](https://testflightapp.com)

Or [jailbreak](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOS_jailbreaking) your iPhone and you can use [this method](http://itigerraj.blogspot.in/2012/09/install-apps-on-devices-without.html) (below answer)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but your answer is irrelevant to my question. You are addressing in sense of testing app but i am asking in sense of application deployment.

Comment: i think your question is edited after my answer..

Comment: Yes i did , coz it seems test word in the question have redirect to somewhere else.